# Make Valid jSON String using character replacements

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am writing an **iOS app** in **Swift 4.2**

Server is responsing bad quality json with invalid characters. I have to replace some characters to make it a valid json string but I am unable to.

**Server response String:**

> {\"fieldsets\":[{\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"categories\",\"value\":\"Equity\"},{\"alias\":\"subCategory\",\"value\":\"[\r\n  \\"Banking\\",\r\n  \\"FMCG\\",\r\n  \\"Infrastructure\\",\r\n  \\"International Funds\\",\r\n  \\"Large Cap\\",\r\n  \\"Large & Mid Cap\\",\r\n  \\"Mid Cap\\",\r\n  \\"Balanced Fund\\",\r\n  \\"Multi Cap\\",\r\n  \\"Others\\",\r\n  \\"Pharma\\",\r\n  \\"Tax Planning\\",\r\n  \\"Daily\\",\r\n  \\"Small Cap\\",\r\n  \\"Mid & Small Cap\\",\r\n  \\"Diversified\\"\r\n]\"},{\"alias\":\"icon\",\"value\":\"/media/1138/equity.png\"}],\"alias\":\"categoriesSubCategories\",\"disabled\":false,\"id\":\"170e1ba0-6f05-4a11-a2a6-04e108e7fa1f\",\"releaseDate\":null,\"expireDate\":null,\"allowedMemberGroups\":\"\"},{\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"categories\",\"value\":\"Balanced\"},{\"alias\":\"subCategory\",\"value\":\"[\r\n  \\"Debt-Oriented Aggressive\\",\r\n  \\"Debt-Oriented Conservative\\",\r\n  \\"credit opportunities\\",\r\n  \\"Equity Oriented\\",\r\n  \\"Asset Allocation\\",\r\n  \\"Others\\",\r\n  \\"Yearly\\",\r\n  \\"Advance\\"\r\n]\"},{\"alias\":\"icon\",\"value\":\"/media/1139/balanced.png\"}],\"alias\":\"categoriesSubCategories\",\"disabled\":false,\"id\":\"aabf640c-1ba4-4136-9dd0-79f3dfd6b79b\",\"releaseDate\":null,\"expireDate\":null,\"allowedMemberGroups\":\"\"},{\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"categories\",\"value\":\"Tax Saver\"},{\"alias\":\"subCategory\",\"value\":\"[\r\n  \\"Any\\"\r\n]\"},{\"alias\":\"icon\",\"value\":\"/media/1140/tax-saver.png\"}],\"alias\":\"categoriesSubCategories\",\"disabled\":false,\"id\":\"fac9c316-16dc-48ab-bc0d-e8c22c02378f\",\"releaseDate\":null,\"expireDate\":null,\"allowedMemberGroups\":\"\"},{\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"categories\",\"value\":\"Debt\"},{\"alias\":\"subCategory\",\"value\":\"[\r\n  \\"Liquid\\",\r\n  \\"FMP\\",\r\n  \\"Gilt Medium & Long Term\\",\r\n  \\"Gilt Short Term\\",\r\n  \\"Income\\",\r\n  \\"Others\\",\r\n  \\"Short Term\\",\r\n  \\"Ultra Short Term\\",\r\n  \\"Mid Cap\\",\r\n  \\"Small Cap\\",\r\n  \\"Floaters\\",\r\n  \\"Gilt Fund\\",\r\n  \\"Dynamic Bond\\"\r\n]\"},{\"alias\":\"icon\",\"value\":\"/media/1141/debt.png\"}],\"alias\":\"categoriesSubCategories\",\"disabled\":false,\"id\":\"ef1efeda-3334-4a9b-bda7-afff76474a40\",\"releaseDate\":null,\"expireDate\":null,\"allowedMemberGroups\":\"\"}]}

I am trying to use:

```
     let convertedStr = jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\r\\n", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
   let convertedStr2 = convertedStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
  let convertedStr3 = convertedStr2.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"[", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
 let convertedStr4 = convertedStr3.replacingOccurrences(of: "]\"", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

It's not working out.

Comment: Chances are that the server response is OK, and that the additional backslashes etc are only from the *debugger output.*  – Better use `print(serverResponse)` from your code.

Comment: No, I need to replace characters

Comment: Could you give the `(NS)Data` response to be sure? `print("Response data: \(serverData as NSData)")`?

Comment: I copy pasted what the result, and in fact, just doing `replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")` works. The rest is JSON stringified inside JSON, so you shouldn't touch it.

Comment: @Larme You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `convertedStr3` and `convertedStr4` should look like this**:

```
let convertedStr3 = convertedStr2.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"[", with: "[", options: .literal, range: nil)
let convertedStr4 = convertedStr3.replacingOccurrences(of: "]\"", with: "]", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

Your code didn't entirely work because you were deleting characters like `[` and `]` which represent array in json. To fix it, notice I added in both of them `with: "[",` and `with: "]",` which makes possible replacing:

- `"[` with `[` in convertedStr3
- `]"` with `]` in convertedStr4

Try to `print(convertedStr4)` and you should be able to copy the result and check it [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate the json is in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of `\r\n`, it should be "\r\n" or nothing because they are inside JSON (JSON Stringified within JSON).

So either of this:

```
let convertedStr = jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")
```

or

```
let convertedStr = jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "\\r\\n")
```

should be enough.

No need for the other modifications. I'd recommend to fix it on the back-end part.

The back-end should send you this (which is valid):

```
{\"fieldsets\":[{\"alias\":\"categoriesSubCategories\",\"allowedMemberGroups\":\"\",\"id\":\"170e1ba0-6f05-4a11-a2a6-04e108e7fa1f\",\"expireDate\":null,\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"categories\",\"value\":\"Equity\"},{\"alias\":\"subCategory\",\"value\":\"[\\r\\n \\\"Banking\\\",\\r\\n \\\"FMCG\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Infrastructure\\\",\\r\\n \\\"International Funds\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Large Cap\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Large & Mid Cap\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Mid Cap\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Balanced Fund\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Multi Cap\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Others\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Pharma\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Tax Planning\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Daily\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Small Cap\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Mid & Small Cap\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Diversified\\\"\\r\\n]\"},{\"alias\":\"icon\",\"value\":\"\\/media\\/1138\\/equity.png\"}],\"releaseDate\":null,\"disabled\":false},{\"alias\":\"categoriesSubCategories\",\"allowedMemberGroups\":\"\",\"id\":\"aabf640c-1ba4-4136-9dd0-79f3dfd6b79b\",\"expireDate\":null,\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"categories\",\"value\":\"Balanced\"},{\"alias\":\"subCategory\",\"value\":\"[\\r\\n \\\"Debt-Oriented Aggressive\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Debt-Oriented Conservative\\\",\\r\\n \\\"credit opportunities\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Equity Oriented\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Asset Allocation\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Others\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Yearly\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Advance\\\"\\r\\n]\"},{\"alias\":\"icon\",\"value\":\"\\/media\\/1139\\/balanced.png\"}],\"releaseDate\":null,\"disabled\":false},{\"alias\":\"categoriesSubCategories\",\"allowedMemberGroups\":\"\",\"id\":\"fac9c316-16dc-48ab-bc0d-e8c22c02378f\",\"expireDate\":null,\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"categories\",\"value\":\"Tax Saver\"},{\"alias\":\"subCategory\",\"value\":\"[\\r\\n \\\"Any\\\"\\r\\n]\"},{\"alias\":\"icon\",\"value\":\"\\/media\\/1140\\/tax-saver.png\"}],\"releaseDate\":null,\"disabled\":false},{\"alias\":\"categoriesSubCategories\",\"allowedMemberGroups\":\"\",\"id\":\"ef1efeda-3334-4a9b-bda7-afff76474a40\",\"expireDate\":null,\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"categories\",\"value\":\"Debt\"},{\"alias\":\"subCategory\",\"value\":\"[\\r\\n \\\"Liquid\\\",\\r\\n \\\"FMP\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Gilt Medium & Long Term\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Gilt Short Term\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Income\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Others\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Short Term\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Ultra Short Term\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Mid Cap\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Small Cap\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Floaters\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Gilt Fund\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Dynamic Bond\\\"\\r\\n]\"},{\"alias\":\"icon\",\"value\":\"\\/media\\/1141\\/debt.png\"}],\"releaseDate\":null,\"disabled\":false}]}
```

or, withouth the antislashes:

```
{"fieldsets":[{"alias":"categoriesSubCategories","allowedMemberGroups":"","id":"170e1ba0-6f05-4a11-a2a6-04e108e7fa1f","expireDate":null,"properties":[{"alias":"categories","value":"Equity"},{"alias":"subCategory","value":"[\r\n \"Banking\",\r\n \"FMCG\",\r\n \"Infrastructure\",\r\n \"International Funds\",\r\n \"Large Cap\",\r\n \"Large & Mid Cap\",\r\n \"Mid Cap\",\r\n \"Balanced Fund\",\r\n \"Multi Cap\",\r\n \"Others\",\r\n \"Pharma\",\r\n \"Tax Planning\",\r\n \"Daily\",\r\n \"Small Cap\",\r\n \"Mid & Small Cap\",\r\n \"Diversified\"\r\n]"},{"alias":"icon","value":"\/media\/1138\/equity.png"}],"releaseDate":null,"disabled":false},{"alias":"categoriesSubCategories","allowedMemberGroups":"","id":"aabf640c-1ba4-4136-9dd0-79f3dfd6b79b","expireDate":null,"properties":[{"alias":"categories","value":"Balanced"},{"alias":"subCategory","value":"[\r\n \"Debt-Oriented Aggressive\",\r\n \"Debt-Oriented Conservative\",\r\n \"credit opportunities\",\r\n \"Equity Oriented\",\r\n \"Asset Allocation\",\r\n \"Others\",\r\n \"Yearly\",\r\n \"Advance\"\r\n]"},{"alias":"icon","value":"\/media\/1139\/balanced.png"}],"releaseDate":null,"disabled":false},{"alias":"categoriesSubCategories","allowedMemberGroups":"","id":"fac9c316-16dc-48ab-bc0d-e8c22c02378f","expireDate":null,"properties":[{"alias":"categories","value":"Tax Saver"},{"alias":"subCategory","value":"[\r\n \"Any\"\r\n]"},{"alias":"icon","value":"\/media\/1140\/tax-saver.png"}],"releaseDate":null,"disabled":false},{"alias":"categoriesSubCategories","allowedMemberGroups":"","id":"ef1efeda-3334-4a9b-bda7-afff76474a40","expireDate":null,"properties":[{"alias":"categories","value":"Debt"},{"alias":"subCategory","value":"[\r\n \"Liquid\",\r\n \"FMP\",\r\n \"Gilt Medium & Long Term\",\r\n \"Gilt Short Term\",\r\n \"Income\",\r\n \"Others\",\r\n \"Short Term\",\r\n \"Ultra Short Term\",\r\n \"Mid Cap\",\r\n \"Small Cap\",\r\n \"Floaters\",\r\n \"Gilt Fund\",\r\n \"Dynamic Bond\"\r\n]"},{"alias":"icon","value":"\/media\/1141\/debt.png"}],"releaseDate":null,"disabled":false}]}
```

You can pass the second one into a JSON validator, it's valid. The first one isn't really because "\r\n" arent' correctly escaped.

In another hand, there is no interest in use pretty printed in a json, and I'd say less sense in a JSONStringified one. That just adds tabs, new lines char, that add noises, and memory to the request.